# onHiddenProperty event for PopOver Control

Tags: javafx, controlsfx

I have a `PopOver ControlsFX` and I want to create an event every time disappears. You searched information and I think it is done with the method onHiddenProperty but I cannot apply it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if it has lost the focus which means that the popover disappears:

```
popOver.focusedProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    if (oldValue){    
        // oldValue is true -> current value is false-> no focus               
        // TODO your code here
    }
});
```